# SQL Server: Which License? Any alternatives?

Tags: database, licensing, sql, sql-server, relational-database

I'm working on a project which at the moment is not being used for any commercial purposes, and I'm managing the data by using a SQL Server Database.

I read [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019-pricing#CP_StickyNav_1) that I should pay for it if I ever wanted to upload this database in a productive environment.
So my question is: Is there any alternative to keep using it for free? 
If there's not, could I use the *Express* edition until I have 10GB of data?

The thing is I'm using EF Core to connect to the database, so I'm pretty attached to SQL Server.

Comment: We usually do not give licensing advice for specific products on this site - but regarding the current SQL Express edition, look [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/2/9/e29a9331-965d-4faa-bd2e-7c1db7cd8348/SQL_Server_2019_Licensing_guide.pdf), the guide tells you the restrictions of the Express edition, <10GB of data is just one constraint among some others. And if you have further questions about the licenses, you should ask in a Microsoft forum.

Comment: Thanks @DocBrown, I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 4):

> The thing is I'm using EF Core to connect to de database, so I'm pretty attached to SQL Server.

No, you are not.

EF Core contains [a bunch of providers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), including Sqlite, PostgreSQL, and MySql.

Googling for specific databases [gives you more information](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) about the ability to use them with EF Core.